# Software (free) which convert Word doc to Latex (TeX file)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using WinEdt Build: 20170413(v.10.2) - 64 bit for WIN 10, 8, and 7, can anyone recommend on the right software (free) which Convert Word document to Latex. For equations I use MathType version 7.4.4.516.

I used http://www.wordtolatex.com/ software, but now it is not working.

Any recommendations?

Ofer, Email: oferaluf@bezeqint.net